# object-fit alternative for IE for a video with 100% width and set height

Tags: html, css

I have a video that fits in a container and has a width of 100% and a fixed height of 750px.  The video has been set to object-fit: fill, and this works perfectly on all browser apart from..... you guessed it IE!  I understand that object-fit is not supported in IE and wonder if anyone knows a workaround?

```
 #mainContainer {
          width: 100%;
          height: 750px;
          border-bottom: solid 4px #9B51E0;
          position: relative;
          }
 #mainVideo {
          width: 100%;
          height: 750px;
          object-fit: fill;
          position: absolute;
          opacity: 0.85;
          }

 <div id="mainContainer">
     <video id="mainVideo" autoplay loop>
          <source src="video.mp4">
     </video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprising at all ;-) IE doesn't support object-fit property, but there are polyfills for that. 
I always use this one: https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images

**EDIT**:
And for videos
https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill

Comment: Great, thanks for the link!  I will check it out and let you know how I get on. IE will not beat me!

Comment: Checked out the link and certainly helped to point me in the right direction, thanks!